# Community detection with igraph in Python

Tags: python, social-networking, igraph

I need to detection communities in network.
However, I can not get the membership

```
# Script
from igraph import *

karate = Graph.Read_Pajek("karate.gml")
karate.simplify()
cl = karate.community_fastgreedy()
print cl.membership # ---> Not work
```

Anyone knows how to get members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method returns a full dendrogram, so you need to convert it to a clustering first.

```
from igraph import *
karate = Nexus.get("karate")
cl = karate.community_fastgreedy()
cl.as_clustering().membership

# [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
#  2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```